# Ubuntu 14.04.01 corrupted

Tags: system-installation, uefi

I installed 14.04.01 on a Macbook Pro purchased in 2009.   For the install I made the mac an Ubuntu only machine.   I had to reinstall to try to fix an error i caused and in the process corrupted the hard drive.   Now I'm unable to boot from the install disk because it can't find EFI.   What can I do to fix this?   If I can't boot from the DVD I can't install Ubuntu and the hard drive is trashed.   Please help.

I'm a newbie.....

Comment: And I tried to select the Install option after I got the EFI error and it just hung.

Answer (score 0):

You now have only 2 options:

1. Restore your [system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (you're definitely user type 4)
2. Order an Apple Recovery DVD

As you probably don't have #1 (or you wouldn't be asking this question) you should starting making system back-ups after you've painstakingly restored your system so this never happens again...